# Aplicacion Java Web Tarea que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo

Tags: java-ee

estoy desarrollando una aplicación Java Web en el cual tengo que hacer que unas tareas se ejecuten cada cierto tiempo, una de ellas es calcular unas horas de un préstamo realizado (que se almacena en base de datos), si dicho préstamo ya tiene el número de horas transcurridas desde su creación, se debe hacer una tarea como por ejemplo insertar datos en otra tabla, notificar al usuario, etc.

Es la primera vez que debo hacer algo así en Java Web y pues no tengo idea alguna para ello (o por lo menos que sea óptima y segura), sé que existe el Timer y TimerTask

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
@Stateless
public class LoanBean{

    Timer timer;

    public LoanBean() {
        checkLoans();
    }

    public void checkLoans() {
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Tarea ejecutándose");
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 10, 1000);
    }

}
```

Parece funcionar bien en cuanto a que cada cierto tiempo la tarea se ejecute pero solo cuando se interactúe con este EJB, la idea es que se ejecute cuando la aplicación esté montada en el servidor de aplicaciones ya que si lo reinicio la tarea ya no se ejecuta hasta que no vuelva interactuar con este EJB (abrír la página en el navegador web), en este caso utilizo Oracle WebLogic como servidor de aplicaciones

Comment: Hola primero que nada comenta que has intentado hacer, ¿en que parte presentas error?, edita tu pregunta agregando más detalle, de lo contrario será cerrada: Por favor ve a dar el [tour] y verás la forma correcta de [ask]

Comment: @Ventur ya lo he editado

Comment: Pregunta, ¿está tarea deberá estar ejecutándose  prácticamente 24/7 ?, ¿Usarás JSF como fRamework MVC?

Comment: @Ventur si, efectivamente que se ejecute 24/7 cada 5 minutos pero como habia comentado, no sé si sea optimo o qué podria utilizar para ello, y lo de JSF pues es lo que estoy utilizando en el desarrollo con los ManagedBean y estos comunicándose con los EJB

Comment: Si tendrás una tarea que prácticamente estará  corriendo cada X tiempo. Lo ideal será usar Quartz o  mediante un crontab programar la tarea para que este corriendo.

Comment: También puedes hacer un proceso en batch el cual revise las horas transcurridas, y lo puedes registrar en tareas programadas de windows o en el crontab de linux.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que mencionas deberías usar algo como [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el propio Spring a traves de la anotacion @Scheduled:

Un Ejemplo por java config:

```
   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = SEGUNDOS_TAREA_MENSAJE)
   public void tareaProgramada() {
       // Aqui pondrías el código que ejecutaras cada SEGUNDOS_TAREA_MENSAJE segundos

       LOG.info("Me Ejecuto Cada "
           .concat(String.valueOf(SEGUNDOS_TAREA_MENSAJE/1000))
           .concat(" Segundos Mostrándote: ")
           .concat(new Date().toString()));
    }
```

Aqui tienes mas información sobre @Schedule
[Documentación Schedule](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/)

Answer (score 0):

El quartz es cofigurable pero a veces hace que se cuelgue tu servidor, con el @Scheduled de Spring dependes de librerias externas, por lo que te recomiendo que uses las clases del mismo Java y trabajes con el MultiThreading del Java

```
public class MiServicio extends TimerTask{
    private Timer timer;

    public MiServicio() {
        timer = new Timer(true);// indicador de que es un daeomon para prioridad de ejecución
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 4*60*60*1000); // ejecución inmediata y luego cada 4 horas
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ejecuta tu código de procesamiento 

        // valida tu condicion de salida y 
        timer.cancel(); // termina la ejecución periodica
    }

}
```